# Case Object cannot show Case Owner, Contact Name, Account Name correctly

Tags: visualforce, case, contact, standard-objects, owner

I used a VF Page and created a button that used this VF Page. Is anybody know why the value of Case Owner doesn't show correctly, my code is like this:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!Case.Owner}" />
```

The data type of this value is `Lookup(User,Queue)`. Does it matter? And I meet the same situation with Contact Name and Account Name. Their markup I use is:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!Case.Contact}" />
<apex:outputText value="{!Case.Account}" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems:

- You should use the `<apex:outputField>` component
- The actual field API Names end with `Id`

Here is a simple demo page to illustrate how to display these fields properly:

```
<apex:page Standardcontroller="Case">
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:outputField value="{!Case.OwnerId}" />
            <apex:outputField value="{!Case.ContactId}" />
            <apex:outputField value="{!Case.AccountId}" />
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

These fields are actually named `OwnerId`, `ContactId`, and `AccountId`, despite being displayed in the UI without that `Id` suffix. And the field itself simply holds the Id of the related object. The standard `Page Layout` UI and the `<apex:outputField>` component perform some magic to display a linked name instead, but that's not the underlying data structure.